# Xamarin Forms - access controls in a list view from the parent page code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms how do we access a ListViews controls from the code-behind of the parent page?

I want to set some properties but unsure how to access them.

EG if the parent page is MyPage, with a ListView  called MyList which contains Address and Name labels, from the MyPage code-behind how could I set, say the Address label opacity?

Comment: Hi, some questions: 1) can you post the relevant XAML and code behind? 2) Why don't you set these properties through the MVVM model binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these 2 properties are not meant to be within `ListView.Items` I would recommend to get familiar with [BindableProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties). 
`MyList` should expose 2 `BindableProperties`:

- Address
- Name

So it will be possible to use `DataBinding` on those.
 You could also create an `AddressOpacity` and bind it value directly to representing `Label.Opacity`. However if you want to hide/show the label I would recommend to use `Label.IsVisible` instead.

**Alternative not recommended way:**
Create public methods in your `ListView` in order to be able to manipulate different UI props.